# GitHub Issue Template lookup fields

Tags: github, yaml, github-issues

We are trying to create our custom issue forms with yaml and would like to include a field that allow us to link an issue with other issues. Our idea is to have a field like the asignee ones where clicking on the gear icon you can select option from a dynamic list
[image]
where you can search other issues and select one or more.
Do you know if this is feasible? I was reading GitHub documentation and didn't find a type that fit our needs.